# Как поставить иконку по центру img?

Tags: html, css

При наведении на на картинку должен появляться глаз как на макете, что только не пробовал, но никак не могу понять как это сделать, будь это просто бэкграунд было бы проще в разы, а тут img тэг и тэг i.
p.s использую font-awesome

[image: Вот такая лажа получается]

[image: А так должно быть]

```css
.work-cards-img {
  min-width: 337px;
  height: 100%;
}

.fa-eye {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 50px;
  align-self: center;
  position: relative;
}

.work-cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-cards-container">
  <div class="work-cards">
    <i class="fal fa-eye "></i><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/pb_lF8VWaPU/download?force=true&w=640" alt="" class="work-cards-img">
    <i class="fal fa-eye"></i><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/2-1wvS-jZZQ/download?force=true&w=640" alt="" class="work-cards-img">
    <i class="fal fa-eye"></i><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/89xuP-XmyrA/download?force=true&w=640" alt="" class="work-cards-img">
    <i class="fal fa-eye"></i><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/CB4z0uTFSYg/download?force=true&w=640" alt="" class="work-cards-img">
    <i class="fal fa-eye"></i><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/w33-zg-dNL4/download?force=true&w=640" alt="" class="work-cards-img">
    <i class="fal fa-eye"></i><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/01voTCIdeWw/download?force=true&w=640" alt="" class="work-cards-img">
    <i class="fal fa-eye"></i><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/kylL5DcscOA/download?force=true&w=640" alt="" class="work-cards-img">
    <i class="fal fa-eye"></i><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/rnwO_5kZwx8/download?force=true&w=640" alt="" class="work-cards-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы не рекомендовал устанавливать `position: relative` элементом,у которых `display: inline`. Плюс у самих font-awesome элементы `i::before` тоже `position: relative`.

```css
.work-card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.work-card img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.fa-eye {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #000;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 100px;
  top: 70px;
}

.fa-eye::before {
  display: none;
}
.work-card:hover img{
  margin-top:-50px;
}
.work-card:hover .fa-eye{
line-height:50px;
}
.work-card:hover .fa-eye::before {
  display: block;
}

.work-cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="work-cards-container">
  <div class="work-cards">
    <div class="work-card"><i class="fal fa-eye"></i><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/pb_lF8VWaPU/download?force=true&w=640" alt="" class="work-cards-img">
    </div>
    <div class="work-card"><i class="fal fa-eye"></i><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/2-1wvS-jZZQ/download?force=true&w=640" alt="" class="work-cards-img">
    </div>
    <div class="work-card"><i class="fal fa-eye"></i><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/89xuP-XmyrA/download?force=true&w=640" alt="" class="work-cards-img">
    </div>
    <div class="work-card"><i class="fal fa-eye"></i><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/CB4z0uTFSYg/download?force=true&w=640" alt="" class="work-cards-img">
    </div>
    <div class="work-card"><i class="fal fa-eye"></i><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/w33-zg-dNL4/download?force=true&w=640" alt="" class="work-cards-img">
    </div>
    <div class="work-card"><i class="fal fa-eye"></i><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/01voTCIdeWw/download?force=true&w=640" alt="" class="work-cards-img">
    </div>
    <div class="work-card"><i class="fal fa-eye"></i><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/kylL5DcscOA/download?force=true&w=640" alt="" class="work-cards-img">
    </div>
    <div class="work-card"><i class="fal fa-eye"></i><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/rnwO_5kZwx8/download?force=true&w=640" alt="" class="work-cards-img"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwbYN.png вот что вышло(

Comment: @RuslanHellfire Немного исправил

Comment: спасибо большое, теперь всё как надо, теперь надо будет размеры увеличить

Comment: Увеличивая размеры блоков/картинок не забудьте увеличивать отступы. Так как размеры не относительные и привязаны к пикселям, отступы тоже приходится указывать в пикселях.

Comment: И вообще, по-уму идеально было бы сделать через тег `<picture>` и `<svg><img>` вместо font-awesome.

Comment: спасибо за советы